# Adding @fontface doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts

Please excuse my ignorance but my head is starting to spin trying to figure this out.

My wordress website was fine with the google webfont I was using. But then I noticed it looks terribly faded in Internet Explorer. After some googling I discovered one solution could be to use the "kit" instead eg from fontsquirrel (although I don't know if this is true or not). So I got the "webkit" for my font. I uploaded the .eot, .woff, .ttf, and .svg files to a folder titled "fonts" in my child theme folder. I then took the code from the webkit's stylesheet and added "/fonts" to each url line (see below code), and pasted the code into the custom CSS section (my child theme has a custom CSS box beside the universal font section). This does not show my Gruppo font in anywhere, let alone Internet Explorer.  Am I following the right steps to make my font look unfaded in Internet Explorer? If so, what am I doing wrong?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'grupporegular';
src: url('/fonts/gruppo-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/gruppo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/gruppo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/gruppo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/gruppo-regular-webfont.svg#grupporegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: How are you using the font-family for 'grupporegular'? And is your font folder inside of your CSS folder?

Comment: Have you checked to see if your webserver will return the font files?  Depending on the server configuration, it may or may not respond to the request for extensions that it does not recognize.

Comment: Ok, wow, that did it. But the font still looks faded in IE. Any suggestion on how to make the font look good (unfaded) in IE?

Comment: You are saying it looked "faded" in IE even when it didn't work, right? Then the IE issue would have nothing to do with the font-face. Look elsewhere. Do you have any IE-specific CSS, IE-specific classes?